# ng-repeat and select box filtering

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an article list and categories. All I need is updating the article list based on selected category.

I can populate the list with all the articles, I've no problem on that part. But I could not populate the category select box and I could not bind a function to category list's on change event.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
function contrArticles($scope, $http) {
    $scope.articles = [];
    $scope.categories = [];
    $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'dbOps.aspx?act=articleList' }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.articles = data.Table;
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('http error');
        }
    );

    $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'dbOps.aspx?act=categoryList' }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.categories = data.Table;
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('http error');
        }
    );

    $scope.selectCategory = function () {
        $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'dbOps.aspx?act=categoryList&catID=' + $scope.category}).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.categories= data.Table;
            }).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('http error');
            }
        );
    }
}
</script>

  <div ng-controller="contrArticles">
    <ul class="article_list">
      <li ng-repeat="article in articles | filter:search">
        <a href="#" title="article title here">
          <span class="date">
            <span class="month">{{ article.dt_month }}</span>
            <span class="day">{{ article.dt_day }}</span>
            <span class="year">{{ article.dt_year }}</span>
          </span>
          <img ng-src="images/news/{{ article.id }}.jpg" alt="{{ article.title }}" class="thumb" />
          <div class="summary">
            <span class="article_title">{{ article.title }}</span>
            <span class="short">{{ article.content }}...</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li ng-show="(articles | filter:search).length==0">No article found</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

    <select class="combobox" ng-change="selectCategory ()" ng-model="category">
      <option value="">Show all</option>
      <option ng:repeat="s in sports" value="{{ s.id }}">{{ s.tag }}</option>
    </select>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I found the issue, I placed the select box out of the controller and I didnt notice that. I also used ng-select and solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in `$scope.selectCategory`. This:

```
'dbOps.aspx?act=categoryList&catID='$scope.category}).
```

should be:

```
'dbOps.aspx?act=categoryList&catID=' + $scope.category}).
```

Comment: I noticed that and fixed but still the select box is empty and change doesnt get fired.

Comment: I would suggest using the recommended `ng-options` in your select instead of `ng-repeat` also. Can you post a demo of your code with some sample data?

Comment: I found the issue, I placed the select box out of the controller and I didnt notice that. I also used ng-select and solved the problem.